# blender curve tool isn't smooth

Tags: modeling

I am using the curve tool for the first time and sometimes when I duplicate it it isn't smooth.
how can I fix that?
[image: not smooth]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a *Poly* curve, go into the header menu > *Curve > Set Spline Type* and choose *Bezier* instead:

[image]

Once done, as the curve is still straight, press <kbd>V</kbd> to convert to *Aligned*:

[image]